# add new person using ibatis in mysql DB

Tags: mysql, xml, servlets

i want to add person in database using ibatis in j2EE application.
I have a table person in mySQL, servlet,SqlMapConfix.xml,Person.xml and Person.java.
i did many tests but i had the same error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred. Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource config/Person.xml

here the code :
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Controller" >
        <input type="text"  name="nom">
        <input type="text"  name="pren">
        <input type="submit" value="ok">
    </form> 
</body>
```

servlet: Controller.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 String a = request.getParameter("nom");
  String b = request.getParameter("pren");

try{

 Reader rd;
  rd = Resources.getResourceAsReader("config/SqlMapConfig.xml");


  SqlMapClient smc; 
  smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(rd);
    out.println("Going to insert record.....");
  Person em = new Person(a, b);

  smc.insert("Person.insert", em); 

   out.println("Record Inserted Successfully ");

   }catch(SQLException e)
  {e.printStackTrace();}

 }
```

Person.java

```
package controleur;

public class Person {
String nom,prenom;

public Person(String nom, String prenom) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
```

}

Person.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="Person">
<insert id="insert" parameterClass="controleur.Person" >
insert into person(nom, pren)values(#nom#, #prenom#)
</insert>
</sqlMap>
```

SqlMapConfig.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
    PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
```

```
<settings useStatementNamespaces="true"></settings>
<transactionManager type="JDBC">
<dataSource type="simple">
 <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parc"/>
<property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
<property name="JDBC.Password" value=""/>
</dataSource>
</transactionManager>
<sqlMap resource="config/Person.xml "/>
```

i used two package: package config contains *.xml files and package controleur contains the servlet and the java class.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the xml file to where the Pojo was located, in your example move it under `controleur` package where Person.java is located then update the sqlMap as follows.

```
<sqlMap resource="controleur/Person.xml" />
```

Comment: the error was the space betwwen the quote and .xml in this line:<sqlMap resource="config/Person.xml  "/>